# fancybox popup appears behind google maps

Tags: jquery, fancybox

i downloaded fancybox.net and edditted the example file from the download pack.
i added a google maps map. 
and when i click on the iframe link, the iframe popup apears BEHIND the google maps map.
thats not the way i want it offcourse.
what did i do wrong? 
i didn't change the original code from the example file.
see this image for the error:

[image]

---

i dont have online space right know

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
    <title>FancyBox 1.3.1 | Demonstration</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.css" media="screen" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {


            $("#various3").fancybox({
                'width'             : '75%',
                'height'            : '75%',
                'autoScale'         : false,
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none',
                'type'              : 'iframe'
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<a id="various3" style="z-index: 999999" href="http://google.ca">Iframe</a>
<div><p>&nbsp;</p></div><iframe width="900" height="800" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.nl/maps?q=google&amp;oe=utf-8&amp;client=firefox-a&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hl=nl&amp;hq=google&amp;hnear=&amp;t=h&amp;layer=c&amp;cbll=43.432247,-95.58578&amp;panoid=2fPtt4N4mRuitc1wXLm_wg&amp;cbp=13,308.54,,0,14.77&amp;ll=21.371244,-83.320312&amp;spn=39.112201,79.013672&amp;z=4&amp;source=embed&amp;output=svembed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="http://maps.google.nl/maps?q=google&amp;oe=utf-8&amp;client=firefox-a&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hl=nl&amp;hq=google&amp;hnear=&amp;t=h&amp;layer=c&amp;cbll=43.432247,-95.58578&amp;panoid=2fPtt4N4mRuitc1wXLm_wg&amp;cbp=13,308.54,,0,14.77&amp;ll=21.371244,-83.320312&amp;spn=39.112201,79.013672&amp;z=4&amp;source=embed" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">Grotere kaart weergeven</a></small>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it might have something to do with the z-index

Comment: I had the same problem and the following solution helped me:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281002/z-index-and-iframes

Answer (score 1):

It's a Z-index issue. If you set the Z-index for your popup to be something higher, it should show on top.

```
#element {
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Comment: nope. i tried before. when i add z-index to #iframe.. i see the same. also set z-index for the googlemaps to -1, no changes..  
#iframe{ z-index: 999 !important; }

Comment: have you examined the z-indexes using firebug?

it's likely that fancybox uses the maximum z-index: 9999;

Comment: Can you post a link to your page? I bet the Z-index is still the issue. Google maps is tricky with the Z-index stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the z-index **inside** the fancybox .css file.